Why Z3 loop infinitely for 2 simple axioms?
MY QUESTION IS "Why Z3 loop infinitely for 2 simple axioms?"
Hi z3 falls infinite loop with the following 2 axioms:

$(\forall x(\lnot(f_s(x)\hat{=}x))$
$(\forall x_1(\forall x_2((\lnot(x_1\hat{=}x_2))\to(\lnot(f_s(x_1)\hat{=}f_s(x_2))))))$

And the c++ code is as follow
#include "../z3/src/api/c++/z3++.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace z3;
int main() {
    z3::context c;

    z3::sort P = c.uninterpreted_sort("P");
    z3::expr x = c.constant("x", P);
    z3::expr y = c.constant("y", P);

    z3::func_decl next = c.function("next", P, P);
    z3::expr diff_next = forall(x, next(x) != x);
    z3::expr diff_next2 = forall(x,y, implies(x!=y, next(x)!=next(y)));
    
    solver s(c);
    s.add(diff_next);
    s.add(diff_next2);
    switch (s.check()) {
        case unsat:   
            std::cout << "is not valid\n"; break;
        case sat:     
            std::cout << "is valid\n"; break;
        case unknown: 
            std::cout << "unknown\n"; break;
    }
    return 0;
}


Some thoughts:
It is not hard to find that a model $M=\{a,b\}$ and $f_s(a)=b,f_s(b)=a$ that can satisfy the above axioms where:

$(\forall x(\lnot(f_s(x)\hat{=}x))$

$f_s(a)=b\ne a$
$f_s(b)=a\ne b$


$(\forall x_1(\forall x_2((\lnot(x_1\hat{=}x_2))\to(\lnot(f_s(x_1)\hat{=}f_s(x_2))))))$

$((\lnot(a\hat{=}a))\to(\lnot(f_s(a)\hat{=}f_s(a))))$ is true since $(\lnot(a\hat{=}a))$ is false
$((\lnot(a\hat{=}b))\to(\lnot(f_s(a)\hat{=}f_s(b))))$ is true since $f_s(a)=b\ne a=f_s(a)$
$((\lnot(b\hat{=}a))\to(\lnot(f_s(b)\hat{=}f_s(a))))$ is true since $f_s(b)=a\ne b=f_s(a)$
$((\lnot(b\hat{=}b))\to(\lnot(f_s(b)\hat{=}f_s(b))))$ is true since $(\lnot(b\hat{=}b))$ is false



In my opinion, we can process like this:

Adding 1 constant symbol of $c_a$ to instantiate all variables
Applying it to first axiom, we have $c_a\ne f_s(c_a)$ then we know for sure that $f_s(c_a)$ is a different value, we add another constant symbol of $c_b$ to represent $f_s(c_a)$, thus we satisfy $f_s(c_a)=c_b\ne c_a$
Applying the new constant symbol to first axiom, then we have $f(c_b)\ne c_b$, thus we know that $f_s(c_b)$ cannot be represent by $c_b$, but can be represented by all other constant symbols, such as $c_a$
Applying $c_a,c_a$ and $c_b,c_b$ for the second axiom, we got satisfactions
Applying $c_a,c_b$ and $c_b,c_a$ for the second axiom, since $c_b$ is set to represent $f_s(c_a)$, then we need t satisfy $f_s(c_b)\ne c_b$ and $c_b\ne f_s(c_b)$ respectively
By step 3, we know that $f_s(c_b)$ is not conflict with $f_s(c_b)=c_a$ then it is satisfied

With the above steps it is possible to find out limited model for axioms, however Z3 seems to fall into infinite loop for these 2 axiom.
I tried to read the source code to find the reason for that, but it is pretty hard to understand......
Thus I post my question here and hope some one can give me some hint or guide, thanks!

Reason of using constant symbols:

By axiom of specification we have $\forall x_1...x_n\phi(x_1,...,x_n)\vdash\phi(c_1,...,c_n)$
Any combination of constant symbol vector $\left<c_1,...,c_n\right>\in C$ can be satisfied with $\phi(c_1,...,c_n)$, then a model that correspond to $C$ can satisfy $\forall x_1...x_n\phi(x_1,...,x_n)$
If any of the constant symbol vector $\left<c_1,...,c_n\right>\in C$ produce a conflict, this directly contradict with $\forall x_1...x_n\phi(x_1,...,x_n)\vdash\phi(c_1,...,c_n)$. And by first-order-theorem it can be proved that $\forall x_1...x_n\phi(x_1,...,x_n)$ is not consistent


A human-readable rendering of the axioms without all the superfluous brackets that make it impossible to eyeball the scope of the connectives: $\forall x,(f(x)\ne x)$, $\forall x_1,\forall x_2,(x_1\ne x_2\to f(x_1)\ne f(x_2))$.

What is your question?  I don't see any question here.  This is a Q&A site, so we require that the body of your post contain a specific, answerable question that is within the scope of this site.

@d.w. my question is as the title, which is the reason of z3's infinite loop for the 2 simple axioms. I posted some of my understanding to show that I did research into the problem but cannot get an answer.

Please make sure the question is asked in the body of your post.  The title is not just the first sentence of the body; the body should stand on its own.  The title is a summary, but the question should make sense if the title is removed.

@D.W. I've added the question at the very top of the body, and if you can answer it, please help. If you have any other opinion about the way of me asking questions, please also be specific
